# pyserial cannot convert string to float ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, pyserial

Here is some code I am working on. The idea is to use a remote serial terminal to send servo angles to it and have it report the current position of the servo at regular intervals.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import serial
import io
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
from gpiozero import Device, AngularServo

sport = serial.Serial('/dev/rfcomm0', timeout=6)
sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(sport, sport))
Device.pin_factory = PiGPIOFactory()

tservo = AngularServo(17,
                     min_angle= -90,
                     max_angle= 90,
                     min_pulse_width= 1/1000,
                     max_pulse_width= 2/1000)
while True:
        if len(sio.readline()) > 0:
                go_to = float(sio.readline())
                tservo.angle = go_to
        angle_string = str(tservo.angle) + '\n'
        tuned_to = (angle_string.encode())
        sport.write(tuned_to)
        time.sleep(5)
```

It sort of works, but I get these error messages when I try to send a number:

```
Sep  5 12:16:28 magloop1 rfcomm[2354]:     go_to = float(sio.readline())
Sep  5 12:16:28 magloop1 rfcomm[2354]: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

I tried using TextIOWrapper, but it isn't any different.

Comment: Yeah. Empty values (strings) are not intepreted as 0.0. But your program has a logic problem. You read a line, you check that it has data. Nice. But then you read an other line and you convert to float. That line may not have data (and you discarded previous line readed)

Comment: Hmm, so maybe I need to put go_to = sio.readline() and then check if len(go_to) > 0 and then convert it to a float?

Comment: Yes. And possibly with better variable name. You will read your code again, so keep it as obvious as it can be

Comment: You are reading `sio.readline()` two times. It isn't a mathematical equation or function; the return value is (in general) different every time (there are side effects in calling it (the internal state changes)).